# Break a comment at a single line of code in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, comments

Here's a basic one:

> Is it possible to break a comment to allow you to continue to write the code at the very same line in `vb.NET`?

I'm asking because there's a section in my code that I would like to comment the code before the code itself (line by line):

```
'Comment here    <code>
```

instead of

```
<code>    'Comment here
```

I know we can use the tag `Rem` to initialize a comment instead of `'`, but I don't know if it's possible to break the `Rem` (or the `'`) to continue to write the code.

Please, I know that some of you will point out the badness of this kind of procedure. But I would like to know how to do it anyway...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have code after a comment on the same line.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/comments-in-code) states:

> Comments can follow a statement on the same line, or occupy an entire line.

To have a comment precede code, place the comment on the preceding line.